# Can't get out of the loop when I type nothing or press cancel

Tags: java

I can't seem to get out of the loop when I type nothing in the input or I press cancel.
Is there a way out?

```
    While (last == '?'){
        input = (int)(Math.random()*2); 
        if (number == 1){
            answer = "Nice";
        }
        if (number == 2){
            answer = "Okay";
        }
        System.out.println("The answer: " + answer);
        input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Ask a question. (Remember the?)");
        if (input != null && input.length() > 0){
            last = input.charAt(input.length() - 1);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`last` must be initialized outside your loop, but when you enter nothing or cancel the last if statement evaluates to false so `last` is not set to a new value so it will continue to use the previous value which continues to loop.

You should reset `last` to null or an empty string before evaluating that last if statement.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your 'break-the-loop' condition (`if input != null && input.length() > 0`) only assigns a new value to `last` when it's evaluated to `true`, -- but entering nothing causes it to evaluate to false, meaning the value of `last` is unchanged.

Adding the following to the last if block might fix it:

```
else {
    break;
}
```

Additionally, typing something that doesn't end with a question mark ought to break the loop.